# Why does working this slider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKPKPk)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 7000
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  z-index: -99;
}
/* keeps this behind all content */

.carousel .item {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.carousel .one {
  background: url(assets/img/slide3blur.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .two {
  background: url(assets/img/slide2blur.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .three {
  background: url(assets/img/slide1blur.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .active.left {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel container slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
    <div class="item three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this carousel does not work. I Receive this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carousel is not a function
```

You can help me fix this error please?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Check in your html if you have included carousel.js or not.

Comment: you HAVE to include carousel,js in your <head> . that's why you get that error.

Comment: Which carousel plugin you are using and check whether it is included or not

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put jQuery.js before bootstrap.js

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js
```

should come before:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

just click on the setting button (left to JS):

[image]

and then change the order of the 'includes':

[image]

Please note that you should proive the jpg files as well, but the carusel issue was solved.

Comment: can you please give me the link to codepen? I tried to add but do not go

Comment: @JohnSmith did it solve your problem? if so, I'll appreciate if you can mark this question as solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are not include carousel plugin. please add this line in to your head tag

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

these are three lines for bootstrap carousel it will run proper.

Comment: can you please give me the link to codepen? I tried to add but do not go

Comment: @bala watch my answer, he does include these files - look at codepen setting.. he just made it in the wrong order